# Hash the Local-Part of an E-mail Address in R to Obfuscate Values

Tags: r, hash

I am trying to parse an e-mail address field into it's local and domain parts, MD5 hash the local part and then concatenate them back together.  The goal here is to obfuscate the data in our development environment but still allow the field to be joined with other datasets by that field.  I have this kind-of working, but I can't get the parselcl value to return correctly... I was expecting it to be a vector, but it returns as single value.

Here is my code:

```
 library(stringr)
 localp <- gsub("@.*", "", dat$channels.email.address)
 domainp <- gsub(".*@", "", dat$channels.email.address)
 parsedlcl <- digest(localp, "md5", serialize = FALSE)
 dat$channels.email.address <- str_c(parsedlcl, "@", domainp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop the `digest` over all the values in dat$channels.email.address. Otherwise it will just generate a single value as you are experiencing.

Your code would look like this:

```
library(stringr)
library(digest)

localp <- gsub("@.*", "", dat$channels.email.address)
domainp <- gsub(".*@", "", dat$channels.email.address)

for(i in seq_along(dat$channels.email.address)) {
  parsedlcl[i] <- digest(localp[i], "md5", serialize = F)
}

dat$channels.email.address <- str_c(parsedlcl, "@", domainp)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, that worked. I am just learning R and haven't gotten to Loops yet. I thought that R worked a little differently (almost like an Update Statement in T-SQL):   

`UPDATE [tbl] SET [checksum] = HASHBYTES('MD5',[field1])

Comment: But it error'd out 'cause there was no "parsedlcl":

     `library(stringr)
     `library(digest)  
 
     `localp <- gsub("@.*", "", dat$channels.email.address)  
     `domainp <- gsub(".*@", "", dat$channels.email.address)  
     `parsedlcl <- "Hello"  #### so I added this  
   
     `for(i in seq_along(dat$channels.email.address)) {  
         `parsedlcl[i] <- digest(localp[i], "md5", serialize = F)  
     `}  
   
     `dat$channels.email.address <- str_c(parsedlcl, "@", domainp)  

and it worked.  But I thought that vars were dynamic in R, so why did I have to dim one here?